# VB 2010 Compare Stopwatch Time

Tags: vb.net, compare, stopwatch

I wan't to compare this two stopwatch times:

```
01:50:12.543
```

and

```
01:50:12.542
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Create DateTime objects from both and compare those.

Comment: How about `watch1.Elapsed.CompareTo(watch2.Elapsed)`?

Comment: Can you give me code for creating it to DateTime and comparing because i can't do it?

Comment: This is a legitimate, clear question. It should not be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the interval like this:

```
Dim elapsed as TimeSpan
Dim watch1, watch2 as Stopwatch
...
elapsed = watch1.Elapsed.Subtract(watch2.Elapsed)
```

If you convert to DateTime and compare, you only get it to the nearest second. You'd have to subtract the milliseconds separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. First, use [TimeSpan.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert your string values. Then use [TimeSpan.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the difference, and finally [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tell this difference in milliseconds, the answer will be "1.0" in your case:

```
Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("01:50:12.543")
Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("01:50:12.542")
Dim msDiff As Double = ts1.Subtract(ts2).TotalMilliseconds 'answer: 1.0
```